# Allow a user to add picture to web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing web site that allows the user (normally me) to upload pictures and then to display the image on the appropriate page. I am now trying to add this functionality to a new web site.

In visual studio I opened the new web site and did an ‘add existing item’ to copy the model/view/controller from the old web site. Made a few changes to remove unneeded functionality from the code and a few other minor things.
In both I store the image in a folder named /data/Images. When I execute the code for the new site (Lat34North) and add an image, the image gets added, and the everything appears to work (no errors).

Problem:

1. If I look at the folder (new solution) using “File Explorer”, the jpg appears, in this case, on my hard drive and in the correct folder.
2. If I try and access the folder (~/Data/Images) via Visual Studio, the jpg does not show up.
3. When I try and display the image from the web site, I just get that funny little icon you get when the image is not found.

Photo Controller

//

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult PhotoCreate(string CallingState, string masterMarkerID, string markerTitle)
    {
        ViewBag.photoCallingState = CallingState;
        ViewBag.photoMarkerID = masterMarkerID;
        ViewBag.photomarkerTitle = markerTitle;
        return View();
    }


    //
    // POST: /Photo/Create

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [Authorize]

    public ActionResult PhotoCreate(Photo photo, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            photo.PhotoLinkRecID = photo.savePhotoState + photo.saveMarkerID;
            if (photo.PhotoSequence == 0)
            {


                var no_Photo = from s in db.Photo
                               where s.PhotoLinkRecID == photo.PhotoLinkRecID
                               select s;
                int noPhoto = no_Photo.Count();
                int Sequence = (noPhoto * 20);
                photo.PhotoSequence = Sequence;
            }

            photo.PhotoDateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            photo.PhotoCreatedBy = @User.Identity.Name;

            if (photo.fileUpload != null && photo.fileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                // get the file extension

                photo.PhotoLinkRecID = photo.savePhotoState + photo.saveMarkerID; // Create key to link photo to the approiate marker -- // unique record identifier
                photo.PhotoState = photo.savePhotoState;
                photo.PhotoMarkerID = photo.saveMarkerID;

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.fileUpload.FileName);
                var FileExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();
                photo.PhotoFileType = FileExtension;
                db.Photo.Add(photo);  // add new photo record to the DB
                db.SaveChanges();



                photo.PhotoRecID = "Photo" + photo.PhotoID.ToString(); // unique record identifier


                var saveFile = photo.savePhotoState + photo.PhotoRecID + "." + photo.PhotoFileType;           // new file name
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Images"), saveFile);     // save the file

                HttpPostedFileBase hpf = photo.fileUpload as HttpPostedFileBase;
                hpf.SaveAs(path);

                Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
                photo.PhotoHeight = image.Height;
                photo.PhotoWidth = image.Width;
                try
                {

                    //get the date taken from the files metadata
                    PropertyItem pi = image.GetPropertyItem(0x9003);
                    string sdate = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pi.Value).Replace("\0", String.Empty).Trim();
                    string secondhalf = sdate.Substring(sdate.IndexOf(" "), (sdate.Length - sdate.IndexOf(" ")));
                    string firsthalf = sdate.Substring(0, 10);
                    firsthalf = firsthalf.Replace(":", "/");
                    sdate = firsthalf + secondhalf;

                    photo.PhotoDateTaken = sdate;
                }
            catch { }


            try
            {

                double? lat = ImageExtensions.GetLatitude(image);
                double? lon = ImageExtensions.GetLongitude(image);

                if (lat > 1)
                {
                    photo.PhotoLatDirection = "N";
                    string latString = lat.ToString();
                    //photo.PhotoLat = latString.Substring(0, 10);
                    if (latString.Length < 10)
                    {
                        photo.PhotoLat = latString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        photo.PhotoLat = latString.Substring(0, 10);
                    }

                    //photo.PhotoLat  = lat.ToString();
                    photo.PhotoLongDirection = "W";
                    string longString = lon.ToString();
                    if (longString.Length < 10)
                    {
                        photo.PhotoLong = longString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        photo.PhotoLong = longString.Substring(0, 10);
                    }


                    //photo.PhotoLong = lon.ToString();
                }


            }
            catch { }



            }   
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("PhotoEdit", new { id=photo.PhotoID });  
        }

            return View(photo);
```

- The old web site uses EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0
- The new web site uses EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

The other difference between the two are the packages I have installed. Could I be missing one?

Comment: `/Data/Images` folder should be added under your website path... i.e. it should be a relative path from your website root directory... if you use a physical path, e.g. `C:\Data\Images` then the website cannot access it.

Comment: It is. I used add -> new folder in Visual Studio to add the appropriate directory structure. If it was C:\Data\Images, then the hpf.SaveAs(path); would fail because it could not find the directory. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: OK, it may be working now, but what I did to get it to work is strange. I right-clicked on the folder /data/images. Selected add -> existing item. Selected one of the jpg's I had uploaded via my code. I was then able to see the file in visual studio. Deleted the jpg's and the table Photos to give me a fresh start. Executed the code, added a jpg using the above code and everything worked fine. Have some more code to add, before I call this "done", but looks like this strange error has been worked around. I Hope.